# How to stop videos on news sites from overriding my speaker mute

Tags: laptop, internet, speakers

Just recently I have found when clicking on news stories that their advertisement and news videos start up automatically and that if I have set the speakers to mute that it overrides this. I then re-mute the speakers and a few seconds later it is overriden and the sound starts up again. I think this will be a growing common problem as it seems a "new trick" by hungry media sites. Can someone please let me know how to stop it happening?

Comment: Can you give an example of a site that does this?

Comment: The normal way to evade this seems to be adblock, noscipt and friends so the adds never get started. However that does not answer your specific question.

Comment: Just set volume level directly in system.

Comment: Also what browser and OS are you on?

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on speaker icon in the system tray near the clock, select "Playback devices". 
Click on the default device (default is likely named "Speakers") and select "Properties". 
Click on the "Advanced" tab. 
Uncheck "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device".